# Make some obj records non-searchable : SF global search

Tags: lightning-experience, standard-objects, global-search

How can we configure salesforce global search such that, some standard object records should not be searched ?

Comment: Do you want to hide all the records on certain standard objects or only certain type of records. For e.g. you can configure the search results such that user can search only the records owned.

Comment: The requirement is to hide all the records.

Comment: For example - if I say Opportunity then no records of Opportunity should be searched

Comment: @Shri Did you find any solution for this?